# Jenkins Build Error while running WIndows Batch Command

Tags: .net, jenkins

Whenever I run commands using the windows batch command it gives me a certain error that this command is not recognized as an external or internal command. Even though it runs fine in the machine itself where the Jenkins is running. But it gives this error while running even though the environment variables are perfectly configured.

For instance, I was trying to run a dotnet project using windows batch command and it was giving me an error while running the dotnet command, images attached for reference[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwSXv.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhx9b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the commands are installed for all users

if you print where  it will show the details of the location

if it is user specific then it won't work in jenkins as it might be running under different user profile

Comment: It's running under the same profile which is admin. I have checked it locally as well. But this issue is only persisting in Jenkins.